# Pagination not working with pagenavi

Tags: plugins, pagination, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I am using PageNavi and have been searching around trying to figure out why I can't get pagination to work. Currently, the page numbers show but when you click on the page numbers, it goes to a page not found page.

Here are some links I've reviewed:

https://toolset.com/forums/topic/help-to-get-wp-pagenavi-working-for-page-2-onwards/

[pagenavigation not showing the next page just linking back to the main page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53514/pagenavigation-not-showing-the-next-page-just-linking-back-to-the-main-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    /*Query DW Hammer Articles*/
    $counter = 1; //counter tracks the number of the post we're on
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'post_type' => 'news_article',
        'orderby'=> 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $newsQuery = new WP_Query( $args);
    if ( $newsQuery->have_posts()) : while ( $newsQuery->have_posts()) : $newsQuery->the_post();
        ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content', get_post_type() != 'post' ? get_post_type() : get_post_format()); ?>
        <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); endif;?>
    <div class="wp-pagenavi-container">
        <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $newsQuery ) ); wp_reset_query();?>
    </div>
```

Comment: And where do you put this code?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż This code is on the news archive listing page.

Comment: Then it won’t work. You ignore real query and put your own. So the real query can have less results than your query and will generate 404. You should use pre_get_posts and not own WP_Query in such case.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Can you please provide what I should do then because every where I've researched shows to do it similar to how I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to my functions.php file and it worked:

```
function toolset_fix_custom_posts_per_page( $query_string ){
if( is_admin() || ! is_array( $query_string ) )
    return $query_string;

$post_types_to_fix = array(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'news_article',
        'posts_per_page' => 6
    ),
    // add another if you want
    /*
    array(
        'post_type' => 'movie',
        'posts_per_page' => 2
    ),
    */
);

foreach( $post_types_to_fix as $fix ) {
    if( array_key_exists( 'post_type', $query_string )
        && $query_string['post_type'] == $fix['post_type']
    ) {
        $query_string['posts_per_page'] = $fix['posts_per_page'];
        return $query_string;
    }
}

return $query_string;
```

}

add_filter( 'request', 'toolset_fix_custom_posts_per_page' );